# How to change the WindowTitle of alert dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Anyone knows how to change the window title text color and other styles of an alert dialog popped up when you click a list item in preference activity?

I have changed the background but text isn't changing. I'll paste my style code here.

```
<style name="alertDialogThemeLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
       <item name="android:background">#ffaaaaaa</item>
       <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/dialogTitleLight</item>
</style>

<style name="dialogTitleLight">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
       <!-- <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/dialogTitleTextLight</item> -->
</style>

<style name="dialogTitleTextLight">
        <item name="android:textColor">#334455</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
</style>
```

I can't find attribute to change text color.

Comment: Hey, did you ever get this "windowTitleStyle" to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `<item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>`,**#ff0000** - this is color code,you need change it

```
<item name="android:background">#ffaaaaaa</item>, this is doesn't correct, after "#" only be  6 charakters
```

Comment: Background is working. Problem is the textcolor. and last the additional two characters are Alpha values (:

Comment: actually first 2 characters are alpha values. The format is #aarrggbb.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will replace the title of your alert dialog

Create a separate Layout and place textView in that, Apply styles for it in the xml file. Then add that view in this below method :

```
alertDialogObj.setCustomTitle(View);
```

For Your Reference : Click this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Any way to get AlertDialog object? since it is shown by system, I cant change it. Do I need to override the ListItem click handler?

Comment: No, Why you want to override click handler

Comment: Otherwise how can I get the alert dialog instance?

Comment: Ok ok. You override that click handler

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object AlertDialog.Builder.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //set message, title, and icon
        builder.SetTitle("Title");
        builder.SetMessage("Some Question?");

        //set twooption buttons
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Yes", new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>(OnExitDialogClicked));
        builder.SetNegativeButton("No", new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>(OnExitDialogClicked));
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();

        TextView tv = new TextView(dialog.Context);
        tv.Text = "Text";

        dialog.SetCustomTitle(tv);

        dialog.Show();
```